# Script authorization required on a daily basis

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google site with 16 different scripts (one for each page) on it.  Each script prints a list of folders / docs from Google Drive.  I have a trigger on each of the scripts to run once daily, however I get emails every single day that authorization is required for the scripts to run even though every day I go in and approve each individual script.  This has been going on for at least a month.

I've tried changing when the trigger fires as well as deleting the triggers then re-adding them.

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because you have too many scripts and triggers.

I don't know the exact amount one might have, but let's say it is 10. So, when you authorize the 11th, the authorization for the first one is dropped/forgotten.

I searched the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and didn't found an issue report regarding this, or anyone in the old forum that has determined the specific amount. But I remember discussing this and coming to this conclusion about this behavior of re-authorizations. Sorry for not being of more help, I guess you should open an issue report and/or try to verify this behavior yourself.

Comment: There does indeed seem to be a limit.  There are a couple of other people with similar problems.  I'll condense the scripts down.

Answer (score 1):

> Set a limit of 20 triggers per script. This limit takes effect as of May 21, 2012. For scripts created prior to that date, which already have more than 20 triggers, they will keep the existing triggers, but cannot add new ones without removing existing triggers.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes